# Unable to access the variable in template1 which is set in template 2.(refer code)

Tags: coldfusion

See I have 2 templates

```
<cfelseif cntDS eq 0 and cnt3G eq 0 and cntLLME eq 1>
<cfinclude template="template1.cfm">
<!---ID3 Start--->
<cfif session.usergroupid EQ 210 OR session.usergroupid EQ 260>
<cfinclude template="template2.cfm">
</cfif>
<!---ID3 End--->
```

I have to use the variables in “template1.cfm” which are set in “template2.cfm”. But the order of display is as the order of including of these template.
But I am unable to use the variable in template1.cfm which are set in template2.cfm.

But if I change the order of include(template2 then template1) then I am able to access the variables in template1 which are set in template2. But the order of display at front end changes(which is not the requirement of user).

Can anyone please suggest me how can I achieve the desire result.

Comment: I suggest that you step away from your code and flowchart your app.

Comment: You need to step back from your current approach to coding and read up about MVC and use a framework to build your sites. You should not be putting yourself in the situation that variable-creation and view-rendering and intercoupled like this.

Comment: my friend, you are trying to change flow of programming language. Programming language execute top to bottom, I guess you need to write your own interpreter/compiler which execute on bottom to top,lol. I agree with Adam, change to MVC.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use the variables defined in template2.cfm which does exist when your template1.cfm is called, so it will not work.

Either way, you if you do not want to show an error. try using the cfparam at the master page and give it a default value like `<cfparam name="myvariable" default="0">`

So this way if the variable myvariable does not exists in template1.cfm which is called first, it will show you as zero, and if that variable exists in templae2.cfm, it will show that value from the template2.cfm

Did i made it clear, Let me know if I am explaining it on the wrong Path

Regards

Comment: actually I am fetching some the data using query in template 2. Can We set param for query

Comment: You are saying that you are fetching the data using the Query and you need to put that value in the <cfparam - is that correct, if that is the case yes you can, just declare some cfparam at the master page, and when you actual run your query in template2.cfm, do it like this: <cfparam name="myvariable" default="#query.name#">